# How to create a trigger (SQL query) that will limit data entry to 30 in table?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I need to create a trigger that will limit number of rows on 30 in table.

E.g. table has 3 columns: `student_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`.

The maximum number of entries for this table should be 30 students. If there are already 30 entries in the table, then the 31st attempt to insert a student should result in an error that the table is already filled.

Comment: please specify RDBMS you use. Triggers are very vendor-specific topic

Comment: I use MS SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: You can make a `constraint` on the `id`.

Comment: How would that stop the number of rows, @Shmiel ?

Comment: Max id should be 30, or something like an id column that can only go from 1-30 and it auto increments.

Comment: @Shmiel that’s not quite how an auto increment column works. Have you ever deleted a row?

Comment: Yes I know and you would also need to update all subsequent rows that the number should become -1.

Comment: @Shmiel that’s an extremely inconvenient thing to do, especially if those PK values are repeated in any other tables.

Comment: So what is stopping you from at least creating a stub of an insert trigger (because updates and deletes are not relevant)? You simply count the number of rows in the table and then throw an error if that number is greater than 30. That should be sufficient information for you to make an attempt. A little searching (including the documentation) will find examples (good and bad) of triggers.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you not to use a trigger to enforce this.

The easiest method to enforce this is to just limit `student_id` to between 1 and 30:

```sql
ALTER TABLE student
  ADD CONSTRAINT student_max30 CHECK (student_id >= 1 AND student_id <= 30);
```

Given that `student_id` will also have a unique constraint via a `PRIMARY KEY`, you now have a hard limit of 30 rows in the table.

If you use replication and/or ETL, you may want to use a new column for this purpose instead

```sql
ALTER TABLE student
  ADD slot_number tinyint UNIQUE,
  CONSTRAINT student_max30 CHECK (slot_number >= 1 AND slot_number <= 30);
```

Comment: But this also requires one to re-use "old" IDs when any row is deleted- which is generally not a good idea in any real system. And surely we ALL know how common it is to use an identity column as a primary key - another factor that works against this approach. Quite frankly this is more of a kludge IMO.

Comment: @SMor Personally I think that's more of a factor of the column name. It should probably be called `SlotNumber` or similar. You could have a separate `ID` column to use for replication and ETL if necessary. Or putting it another way: a column that has exactly 30 unique possibilities to it is exactly what is necessary to enforce 30 rows